# Can I find the appropriate MirrorAnnotation in a short way?

Tags: java, class, annotations, annotation-processing, annotations-processing-messager

If I want IDE to show an error from annotation processing on the annotation itself, I should use the following form of printMessage():

```
printMessage​(Diagnostic.Kind kind, CharSequence msg, Element e, AnnotationMirror a)
```

But I cannot find a nice and simple way to get that AnnotationMirror.

Using code samples, [these](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/javax.lang.model.element.Element/getAnnotationMirrors) and [these](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/blob/develop/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-core/androidannotations/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/helper/AnnotationHelper.java#L119), combining what I found there, I had found a complicated way:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    Set<? extends Element> classesForBuilder = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(AddBuilder.class);
    for(Element classElement : classesForBuilder){
        if (classElement.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT)) {
            return annoError(classElement, "AnnoBuilder cannot be applied to an abstract class.", AddBuilder.class);
.......

boolean annoError(Element annotatedElement, String message, Class<? extends Annotation> annoClass ){
    for(AnnotationMirror annotationMirror : annotatedElement.getAnnotationMirrors()){
>>>>>>>>if(((TypeElement)annotationMirror.getAnnotationType().asElement())
           .getQualifiedName().toString()
           .equals( annoClass.getCanonicalName())) {
            messager.printMessage(Kind.ERROR, message, annotatedElement, annotationMirror);
        } else {
            messager.printMessage(Kind.ERROR, message+" + no Annotation found.", annotatedElement);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

That works. But I do not like the really terrible second `if`.

I had found a shorter way of comparison through String:

```
if(annotationMirror.getAnnotationType().toString().equals(annoClass.getCanonicalName()))
```

I do not understand why only that super-long way of comparison through many classes is used in all published examples.

But still I would like to have it shorter.

```
if(annotationMirror.getAnnotationType().equals(annoClass))
```

does not work.

Can I compare classes somehow without turning them into names?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for present in the `Types` class and you can use the `isSameType` method like this

```java
annotatedElement.getAnnotationMirrors()
                .stream()
                .filter(annotationMirror -> types.isSameType(annotationMirror.getAnnotationType(), elements.getTypeElement(annoClass.getCanonicalName()).asType()))
                .findFirst()
                .map(annotationMirror -> {
                    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, message, annotatedElement, annotationMirror);
                    return true;
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, message + " + no Annotation found.", annotatedElement);
                    return false;
                });
```

And you should not use Strings literals obtained from types names for comparison like this as it might work differently between intellij and eclipse.